# Why does Rails-4.2.5 NOT install the expected version of Nokogiri (1.6.7.rc4)

Tags: ruby, windows, ruby-on-rails-4

I have installed latest ruby and latest rails on windows 10 x64. All was, at first, running fine.

Then I created new application and could not start the server because of nokogiri 1.6.6.4 x64-mingw32 problems. So I looked on the internet and downloaded latest nokogiri 1.6.7.rc4 x64-mingw32 and updated my gem and made bundle update nokogiri. So the server is working nice now. No problems there.

The thing I would like to know is why, when I create a new application "rails new appname", it always puts in my gem file nokogiri 1.6.6.4?

I uninstalled it but still, every time I create new app, I have to manually edit gem file and update bundle nokogiri so that the server works with the latest nokogiri. Is it possible to change something in the config of ruby/rails/gem so that, on create, it takes the latest nokogiri installed?

Because 1.6.6.4 is not installed until you create an app, then it gets installed again, why?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Exactly what versions of Ruby and what version of Rails are you using? What options are you passing when you create a new rails project?  What does your new project's Gemfile.lock file say respecting dependencies before you change anything?

Comment: ruby 2.2.3., rails 4.2.5., i pass on create just rails new appname with no options. all standard install. gemfile.lock says nokogiri (1.6.6.4-x64-mingw32). i am not really experienced with rails yet. just would be great if is it possible to pass that it would be in lock file after create nokogiri (1.6.7.rc4-x64-mingw32) instead.

Comment: According to RubyGems.org  1.6.7.rc4 - November 22, 2015 x64-mingw32 (4.31 MB) is available.  Have you cleared your local gem cache?  This might be simply a propagation delay.

Comment: No, there is something else going on here.  RubyGems had some problems with installing unwanted pre-release versions earlier.  I wonder if in fixing that they have broken something else.  I see this in Gemfile.lock: '    rails-dom-testing (1.0.7)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)`

Comment: Ah. I think I see the problem.  The rails-dom-testing gem has this in its spec file: `spec.add_dependency "nokogiri", "~> 1.6.0"`. Since it does not expect a prerelease version I suspect that this is blocking the dot-rc4 nokogiri.  You can raise an issue on github for the rails team to look at this: `https://github.com/rails/rails/issues`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed caused by the `rails-dom-testing` dependency as I suspected in my comments.  To fix this, *after you install a new rails project*, `cd` into the new project root directory and do this:

```
gvim ./libexec/bundle/lib/specifications/rails-dom-testing-1.0.7.gemspec
```

Find this line:

```
s.add_runtime_dependency(%q<nokogiri>, ["~> 1.6.0"])
```

and change it to:

```
s.add_runtime_dependency(%q<nokogiri>, ["~> 1.6.7.rc4"])
```

Now run `bundle update`.  This fix will only last until the `rails-dom-testing` gem is updated.

Comment: so after that i will be able to create new project and will not have to edit gemfile and bundle update nokogiri? I will try and get back to you

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is exactly what was needed. i do not get old one anymore. works like a charm. thank you.

Comment: You will need to do this for every new project since the problem gem is going to be initialized with the same gemspec file.  Once a project has been edited then you will only need to do this IF the `rails-dom-testing` gem is updated AND the updated gem has the same problem.  This problem will go away once Nokogiri 1.6.7 is released in any case.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem too.

In my case I wanted to use the most recent Nokogiri, version 1.6.7.X as of this writing. However Rails always included the version that Rubygems has published. If we check what that [version](http://rubygems.org/gems/nokogiri) we'll see it's 1.6.6.4.

Rails makes heavy use of Nokogiri. We can search the [project](https://github.com/rails/rails/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=nokogiri) and see that it's used in integration tests. When you hit `rails new my_app` it builds a [Gemfile](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7f18ea14c893cb5c9f04d4fda9661126758332b5/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/Gemfile) and runs bundle install. So whatever version Rubygems.org has on hand it'll install that one.